# How to use `apply_along_axis` with ndim > 2 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to apply gaussian filtering on the toy digits dataset images. It stores images in a (1797, 8, 8) array. Individually, I can make it work but when I try to apply it for the whole image set with `apply_along_axis`, something goes wrong.

Here is the core example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
images = load_digits().images

# Filter individually
individual = gaussian_filter(images[0], sigma=1, order=0)

# Use `apply_along_axis`
transformed = np.apply_along_axis(
    func1d=lambda x: gaussian_filter(x, sigma=1, order=0),
    axis=2,
    arr=images
)

# They produce different arrays
(transformed[0] != individual).all()
Out: True
```

I tried to change the axis but that did not help. I also checked by, first, simply returning the image/squared values. In these cases, the results seem equivalent. Applying dot product, however, again produces different results.

```
# Squared values
transformed = np.apply_along_axis(
    func1d=lambda x: x ** 2,
    axis=2,
    arr=images
)

# They produce the same arrays
(transformed[0] == images[0] ** 2).all()
Out: True

# Dot product
transformed = np.apply_along_axis(
    func1d=lambda x: np.dot(x, x),
    axis=2,
    arr=images
)

individual = np.dot(images[0], images[0])

# They produce different arrays
(transformed[0] != individual).all()
Out: True
```

I am sure I misunderstand the way these functions work. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** As @hpaulj pointed out in the comments, the `func1d` parameter in `apply_along_axis` takes in only 1d arrays. [See...](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

Comment: Reread the docs, focusing on the `func1d` argument.  That's supposed to take a 1d array as input.  `apply_along_axis` iterates over all the other axes.  Instead it looks like you want to iterate on the first axis, and apply your function to the resulting 2d arrays.  If that's the case, why don't you just do that?  (Even if `apply_along` worked for your case it wouldn't speed up the code; it's an iteration convenience, not a speedup tool.).

Comment: Well, my main purpose was mainly of convenience and then the interest of why it does not work. But yes, just looking at the name `func1d`, I should have guessed... Thanks!